# How do I signify any string or any set of characters in java?

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I am trying to check if there is a string already in my ArrayList list that has the prefix that is the current string (line) in the text reading loop. I tried to use regex as you can see in the line where I wrote line + "\w+" which signifies the current string followed by 1 or more characters, but it does not seem to work? The problem is all about efficiency so I can not use a nested for loop to check against every single previous line in the array list.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Question1 {

/**
 * @param r the reader to read from
 * @param w the writer to write to
 * @throws IOException
 */

public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {

    if(list.size()>=1){
        if(!list.contains(line+"\\w+")){
            l.add(line);
        }
    } else {
        l.add(line);
    }

}

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
            w.println(list.get(i));
        }

}
```

Comment: `contains(CharSequence s)` is not a regex method. [`matches(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) is. --- Also, you need to [escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) the characters in `line` if you insist on using regex: `contains(Pattern.quote(line)+"\\w+")`, but your code would be much better if you simply use [`startsWith(String prefix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-).

Comment: The ArrayList contains method is implemented using a loop so even if it did what you thought, you’d have nested loops. If performance is a real concern, you could look into a prefix tree (a Trie) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 0):

There's no method in List to search by regex. If such a method will exists, then it will have a linear complexity which is not option in your case.

But you can use TreeSet https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html. In tree set items arranged in order, by default in natural order. Natural order on Strings set is lexicographical (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-). This is the order by which you want to exclude string from addition to list.

I have rewrote your code. I didn't use IDE, so do not be strict if the code does not build.

```
public class Question1 {

    public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {

        TreeSet<String> items = new TreeSet<>();

        for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {

        // Add new line to set only if there no greater or equal string in set already
        if(items.floor(line) == null){
            items.add(line);
        }

        // Convert tree set to list
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(items);

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
            w.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This code has complexity O(n * log(N)). It is better performance than in original code.